# How to write a file PkgConfig.pc file that supports both static and shared linking

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking, pkg-config, static-linking

I am writing a little library as a self challenge. I plan to target Linux based systems.

I want to add a `libname.pc` file so as to add support for `PkgConfig`.

Here, is my current file:

```
prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
cphoton_directory=cphoton-0.0
include_directory=${prefix}/include/${cphoton_directory}
library_directory=${exec_prefix}/lib

Name: cphoton-0.0
Description: CPhoton is a basic utility library.
Version: 0.0.0
URL: https://gitlab.com/invitron/cphoton
Cflags: -I${include_directory}
Libs: -L${library_directory} -lcphoton-0.0
Libs.private:
```

I wanted to know if this is compatible for both static and dynamic libs. I tried to use pkg-config with `--static` flag but, it seems to give precedence to `.so` lib. I also tested it with cmake. It links statically only if the dynamic lib is not available.

Is it possible or will I have to provide a separate `.pc` file for static version?

Already visited:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27586503/how-to-use-pkg-config-to-link-a-library-statically
- [https://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html](https://people.freedesktop.org/%7Edbn/pkg-config-guide.html)